# Embedding Spaces in String Variable for Bash Command Read

Tags: bash

How do I embed spaces in my prompt variable for the `read` command in my bash script?

```
rebase_prompt="Proceed with rebase? [y/n] "
read -p $rebase_prompt user_response
```

When this code runs it appears on the terminal as only "Proceed" waiting for my input.

```
Proceed
```

How do I get it to take the full string as the prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By quoting correctly.

```
read -p "$rebase_prompt" user_response
```

Comment: General rule: **Always** quote your variable expansions.